# Order by ordinal_position not producing expected output

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

UPDATE

I have a table with the index in order:

```
fsym_id, currency, x, y, z,
```

and the columns in order

```
currency, fsym_id, x, y, z
```

I would like to extract the names of my index in the right order.

I tried to do the following:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("'",COLUMN_NAME,"'"))
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

But this gives me the ordering of the columns. How can I modify this to return the ordering of the indexes?

Comment: Ordinal position is the order in the index, which is not the same as the order of the columns in the table.

Comment: Please show the query you're using, some sample data, and the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my post

Comment: @barmar 'The position of the column within the table' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Ye well, it does not solve my problem though. I am not sure if it is even possible to extract the names of the output columns in one go. If I do.

Comment: @P.Salmon URL has been updated https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order the values in a `GROUP_CONCAT()` you have to put the `ORDER BY` option in that function. Your `ORDER BY` clause is for ordering the rows; since you're only returning one row, it has no effect.

Also, it's not necessary to use `CONCAT()` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`. If you give multiple values, they're automatically concatenated.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT("'",COLUMN_NAME,"'" ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema'
```

Comment: you sir, is the definition of a superior human being! FANTASTIC JOB!